# How to specify PrivateKey search range in HEX?

Tags: private-key

I am trying to generate random bitcoin Private_Keys in HEX format (32bit) but
I want the randomness to have a value within a specific HEX range, say between

```
18909BDE11F67C97A53C62F45E632EAB58EA0D73A5FAC9EB50295FAD40A57EB5
```

and

```
DD10559E1285B3EE0303B159B8D6D8D0B88E6168D1C1D6000000000000000000
```

The following piece of code in `Python 3` is a start but it simply generates random keys for the curve's entire field which is up to

`FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFEBAAEDCE6AF48A03BBFD25E8CD0364141`

This is the code:

```
generate_private_key():
    return binascii.hexlify(os.urandom(32)).decode('utf-8').upper()
```

How to specify the desired search range expanding on the above code?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you need to use Python for that? Because vanitygen-plus, an unofficial version of vanitygen can be used for that easily.

Comment: Yes, I am looking for suggestions for Python 3 based on the code from the question.

Comment: may be something like this (pseudo code): const(32) + rand(8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use random.
Using your low and high values:

```
import random
def generate_private_key():
    low  = 0x18909BDE11F67C97A53C62F45E632EAB58EA0D73A5FAC9EB50295FAD40A57EB5
    high = 0xDD10559E1285B3EE0303B159B8D6D8D0B88E6168D1C1D6000000000000000000
    return str( hex( random.randrange( low, high ) ) )
```

And then just:

```
print(generate_private_key())
```

Note that you'll probably need to convert this [hex address to wif](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Wallet_import_format), or extract a public key or bitcoin public address from it... If you need more easy Python code for doing this, you can check [these little pieces of code](https://github.com/circulosmeos/bitcoin-in-tiny-pieces).